# IntelliJ + truffle tests

Tags: truffle, truffle-test

I would like to run truffle tests from IntelliJ.

I found a tutorial here: https://charterhouse.github.io/2017/05/12/running-truffle-unit-tests-in-intellij-idea.html

Unfortunately, it does not seem to work anymore.

The blog suggest using `-r truffle/cli truffle test` but `truffle/cli` does not exist in my case.

Is this something that was working before and has changed?

Can anyone suggest how to do this?